Implementing IMU on Hector SLAM
I am working on a project where I need to create a map of buoys on a surface vehicle and return to the starting position after finishing the parkour. The problem is, using Hector SLAM only, both the map and the robot position gets inaccurate after each rotation:

I think my best bet is to use IMU since I do not have odometry data. I found this video of handheld LiDAR mapping from the original creators of Hector SLAM where they mention in the description that they used a cheap IMU;
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8pdObV_df4&list=PL0E462904E5D35E29
Is there a way I can implement IMU to provide position data like they do in the video? I already looked into robot-localization but I could not find a way of using SLAM and IMU together.

You can get your odometry data from hector slam itself by changing some of the parameter in the launch file, I remember these but you may need to adjust them according to your topics, etc:
<remap from="scanmatch_odom" to="odom"/>
<remap from="initialpose" to="trash_initialpose"/>

<!-- Frame names -->
<param name="map_frame" value="map" />
<param name="base_frame" value="base_footprint" />
<param name="odom_frame" value="base_footprint" />

<param name="pub_odometry" value="true" />

<!-- Tf use -->
<param name="use_tf_scan_transformation" value="true"/>
<param name="use_tf_pose_start_estimate" value="false"/>
<param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="false"/>
<param name="pub_map_scanmatch_tra<param name="scan_topic" value="/scan"/>
<param name="tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" value="odom" />

These settings will publish odometry data, then you can publish the imu data and fuse them using robot localization package. You also need to publish the tf between odom and base footprint with a simple odometry handler code. If your environment is full of features you even may not need an imu.
I should mention that getting odometry data based on scan data isn't that much accurate in a environment with few features. Using wheel odometry or maybe a camera will improve your accuracy.

Thanks for the answer, may I ask how I can use a camera to get odometry data? I couldn't find a useful answer the last time I googled it. Also, I can't get wheel odometry since I am working on a sea vehicle.

You should have a stereo or a depth camera like realsense d435, then you can use packages like rtabmap to get odometry data. Its a very pracatical package with a lot of features. If you are planning to use the robot in open environments you can fuse gps data along with your scan and odometry data. If you dont want to use these packages you can always use kalman filter for data fusion. I should mention that algorithms based on camera work best in the environments full of features.
